# Firefox loading old CSS Style sheet instead of loading new one

Tags: firefox, css

Private browsing and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> doesn't seem to be cutting it?

(I've got a lot of ajax loaded content)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263096/css-file-is-not-refreshing-in-my-browser

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by specifying the complete URL of the external style sheet.

Replace this:

```
link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
```

with this:

```
link href="http://www.domainname.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
```

FF instantly loaded the new style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can append the stylesheet URL with a query string to render the cache as no longer valid. For example, a version number.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css?1.1" type="text/css" />
```

This is assuming you are looking for a method to invalidate the cache for everyone. If you are simply looking to clear your own cache, this belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I hit ctrl-shift-delete, it prompts for things to delete, I delete the cache and sometimes the cookies. Then I hit F5.

Answer (score 0):

Simple put some variable behind *.css. For example, ? and time() function.

Comment: I would avoid using time() as this would invalidate the cache on every page load. Unless the styles are being uniquely generated each time (why?), this is inappropriate outside of a development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Stick a version number as a querystring to the CSS file:

```
<link href="/style.css?1" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Or if you want it to never be cached, stick something like the time there:

```
<!-- php -->
<link href="/style.css?<?=time();?>" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- asp.net -->
<link href="/style.css?<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks%>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Firefox Webdeveloper addon. It has a function to disable your cache.

Comment: Fantastic solution. 'Hey visitors, to use this site, you're gonna need Firefox and this addon and then go disable your cache!'